# Ошибка записи в Web Sql

Tags: jquery, javascript, sql

Приветствую, вот такой вот код берет данные с сервера и передает JSONP в javascript, для записи в Web Sql. Но запись не происходят, проверял, данные приходят все правильно.

Вот собственно код:

```
function insertDb(incl) {
    incl.transaction(function(tx) {
        $.getJSON("http://test2.ru/adminbook/getBook.php?time=" + Math.round(newDate().getTime())+ "&callback=?", 
            function(data) {
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO items_main (number_title, title, descr, block_item, content) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", [data[i].num, data[i].title, data[i].descr, data[i].d, data[i].content]);
                    }
            });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А подключение к БД нормально проходит? И хоть с WebSQL я знаком поверхностно, но попробовал бы так:

```
function insertDb(incl) {
    $.getJSON("http://test2.ru/adminbook/getBook.php?time=" + Math.round(newDate().getTime())+ "&callback=?", 
        function(data) {
            incl.transaction(function(tx) {
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO items_main (number_title, title, descr, block_item, content) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", [data[i].num, data[i].title, data[i].descr, data[i].d, data[i].content]);
                }
            });
        });
}
```

Comment: вся проблема была в newDate().getTime() - в функции не срабатывали.